# How do I run all the commands in a bash script?

Tags: mysql, node.js, bash

I am writing a bash script that executes a series of javascript files, all of which are some kind of MySQL queries. The thing is, when the first line of the script executes, it stops the process and does not let the other javascript files to run.

I have already tried using `&` after each line hoping it would run in the background and not stop the flow of execution.

```
#!/bin/bash
# a script to delete the database and create the tables
node createDatabase &
node createTables &
```

When the createDatabase.js file executes properly, there is a callback function which outputs "database created successfully" and the execution just freezes at that.

Comment: To run a command/script in background you should use the `&` operator, not `$`. You can use `strace yourscript.sh` in order to check what is happening.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to "CreateDatabase" and then rush into "CreateTables". You need the DB system to have everything setup before you start Creating tables ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @danlor sorry it was a type, and even after changing to & it doesn't quite solve the issue

Comment: @shellter on a javascript, I could have placed the createTables inside a callback function, any idea how to do that on a bash script?

Comment: can't help with callbacks. I don t understand the need to "cram" all operations into one "event". But you know your use case, and I don't. As you seem to be saying "it's taking too long", you need to debug your CreateDatabase step to see if the time it is taking is reasonable. Again, only you can know what is/should be the reasonable time to perform those operations. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter to be fairly honest, it has more to do with my own convenience than my use case, but I get your point. I will keep that in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue must be from nodejs, Nodejs does not terminate the process on DB creation, you have to call `process.exit(0)` on success or `process.exit(1)` on error otherwise it will wait for the signal to terminate or stop.

Here is a simple Nodejs script that creates a DataBase and exit base on the response from DB.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "my.test.com",
  user: "root",
  password: "password"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydbtest", function (err, result) {
    if (err){
      throw err;
      process.exit(1);
    }
    else{
      console.log("Database created");
      process.exit(0);

    } 

  });
});
```

Now another script that will make tables on the above DB.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "mydb.test.com",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "mydbtest"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err){
    throw err;
    process.exit(1);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err){
      throw err;
      process.exit(1)
    } 
    else{
      console.log("Table created");
process.exit(0)
    }
  });
  } 

});
```

The important section in this code is `process.exit(0)` or `process.exit(1)`.

Now the Bash script will be

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "creating db"
nodejs creatdb.js
echo "creating talbe"
nodejs createtable.js
```

You do not need to send them in the background and now on base one exit code you can exit the script or take any sort of decision.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!. This is exactly what I was looking for and it works like a charm.